# Python- Count the frequency of messages within a date range within per dynamic interval

Tags: python, date, range, intervals

Count the number of messages within a date range per interval. I"m using python 2.6.5 only.

For example
Start date: 12/11/2014
End date: 12/12/2014
Start time: 02:00
End time: 02:05
Interval:  Per 1 min

So this translates to how many messages are between each interval of a minute from start date 12/11 to end date 12/12.
So my out put will look like this: (does not need to have strings min and messages)

```
datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 0) min : 0 messages,
datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 1) min: 1 message,
datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 2) min: 2 messages, 
datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 3) min: 1 message,
datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 4) min : 0 messages,
datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 5) min : 0 messages
```

I believe I accomplish this but its very slow with large datasets. I think because it uses two loops and if the the second loop is extremely large then it takes very long time and does it for each iteration of the first loop.  I need better procedure or alrogithm to accomplish this?

Edit:  I need to include zero for intervals that do not have messages. I'm also trying to find peak,min and average.

```
from datetime import date,datetime, timedelta, time

def perdelta(start, end, delta):
    curr = start
    while curr < end:
        yield curr
        curr += delta


def rdata(table, fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime, interval): 
    date_to_alert = {}
    start_date = datetime(fromDate.year, fromDate.month, fromDate.day, fromTime.hour, fromTime.minute)
    end_date = datetime(toDate.year, toDate.month, toDate.day, toTime.hour, toTime.minute)

    list_range_of_dates = []
    for date_range in perdelta(start_date ,end_date ,interval):
        list_range_of_dates.append(date_range)
    print list_range_of_dates
    index = 0
    for date_range in list_range_of_dates:
        for row in table:    

            print('first_alerted_time 1: %s index: %s len: %s' % ( row['first_alerted_time'], index, len(list_range_of_dates)-1))          
            if row['first_alerted_time'] and row['first_alerted_time'] >= list_range_of_dates[index] and row['first_alerted_time'] < list_range_of_dates[index + 1]:
                print('Start date: %s' % list_range_of_dates[index] )
                print('first_alerted_time: %s' % row['first_alerted_time'])
                print('end date: %s' % list_range_of_dates[index + 1])
                if list_range_of_dates[index] in date_to_alert:
                    date_to_alert[list_range_of_dates[index]].append(row)                                     
                else:
                    date_to_alert[list_range_of_dates[index]] = [row]                       

            elif row['first_alerted_time']:
                print('first_alerted_time 2: %s' % row['first_alerted_time'])        
        index = index + 1  

        print   date_to_alert    
for key, value in date_to_alert.items():
    date_to_alert[key] = len(value)
print   date_to_alert
t1 = []
if date_to_alert:
    avg = sum(date_to_alert.values())/len(date_to_alert.keys())
    for date_period, num_of_alerts in date_to_alert.items():
        #[date_period] = date_to_alert[date_period]
        t1.append( [ date_period, num_of_alerts, avg] )
print t1
return t1

def main():
    example_table = [ 
                {'first_alerted_time':datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 1,45)},
                {'first_alerted_time':datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 2,33)},
                {'first_alerted_time':datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 2,45)},
                {'first_alerted_time':datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 3,45)},
                ]
    example_table.sort()     
    print example_table
    print rdata(example_table, date(2014,12,11), date(2014,12,12), time(00,00,00), time(00,00,00), timedelta(minutes=1))
```

Update:
First attempt for improvement:

Default Dictionary approach

```
def default_dict_approach(table, fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime, interval):
    from collections import defaultdict

    t1 = []
    start_date = datetime.combine(fromDate, fromTime)
    end_date = datetime.combine(toDate, toTime)+ interval


    times = (d['first_alerted_time'] for d in table)
    counter = defaultdict(int)
    for dt in times:
        if start_date <= dt < end_date:
            counter[to_s(dt - start_date) // to_s(interval)] += 1

    date_to_alert = {}
    date_to_alert = dict((ts*interval + start_date, count) for ts, count in counter.iteritems())

    max_num,min_num,avg = 0,0,0
    list_of_dates = list(perdelta(start_date,end_date,interval))
    if date_to_alert:
        freq_values = date_to_alert.values()
        size_freq_values = len(freq_values)
        avg = sum(freq_values)/ size_freq_values
        max_num = max(freq_values)
        if size_freq_values == len(list_of_dates):
            min_num = min(freq_values)
        else:
            min_num = 0
        for date_period in list_of_dates:
            if date_period in date_to_alert:
                t1.append([ date_period.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), date_to_alert[date_period], avg, max_num, min_num])
            else:
                t1.append([ date_period.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), 0, avg, max_num, min_num])

    return (t1,max_num,min_num,avg)
```

numpy approach

```
def numpy_approach(table, fromDate, toDate, fromTime, toTime, interval):
    date_to_alert = {}
    start_date = datetime.combine(fromDate, fromTime)
    end_date = datetime.combine(toDate, toTime)+ interval

    list_range_of_dates = []
    for date_range in perdelta(start_date ,end_date ,interval):
        list_range_of_dates.append(date_range)
    #print list_range_of_dates

    index = 0
    times = np.fromiter((d['first_alerted_time'] for d in table),
                     dtype='datetime64[us]', count=len(table))

    print times
    bins = np.fromiter(list_range_of_dates,
                       dtype=times.dtype)                
    print bin                 
    a, bins = np.histogram(times, bins)  
    print(dict(zip(bins[a.nonzero()].tolist(), a[a.nonzero()])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement [`numpy.histogram()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)  for dates:

```
import numpy as np

times = np.fromiter((d['first_alerted_time'] for d in example_table),
                     dtype='datetime64[us]', count=len(example_table))
bins = np.fromiter(date_range(start_date, end_date + step, step),
                   dtype=times.dtype)
a, bins = np.histogram(times, bins)
print(dict(zip(bins[a.nonzero()].tolist(), a[a.nonzero()])))
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/BEyHWK)

```
{datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 0): 3,
 datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 11, 2, 3): 1}
```

`numpy.historgram()` works even if the step is not constant and `times` array is unsorted. Otherwise the call can be optimized if you decide to use `numpy`.

There are two general approaches that you could use on Python 2.6 to implement `numpy.historgram`:

- `itertools.groupby`-based: the input should be sorted but it allows to implement a single-pass, constant memory algorithm
- `collections.defaultdict`-based: the input may be unsorted and it is also a linear algorithm but it is `O(number_of_nonempty_bins)` in memory

#### `groupby()`-based solution:

```
from itertools import groupby

times = (d['first_alerted_time'] for d in example_table)
bins = date_range(start_date, end_date + step, step)
def key(dt, end=[next(bins)]):
    while end[0] <= dt:
        end[0] = next(bins)
    return end[0]
print dict((end-step, sum(1 for _ in g)) for end, g in groupby(times, key=key))
```

It produces the same output as `histogram()`-based approach.

Note: all dates that are less than `start_date` are put in the first bin.

#### `defaultdict()`-based solution

```
from collections import defaultdict

def to_s(td): # for Python 2.6
    return td.days*86400 + td.seconds #NOTE: ignore microseconds

times = (d['first_alerted_time'] for d in example_table)
counter = defaultdict(int)
for dt in times:
    if start_date <= dt < end_date:
        counter[to_s(dt - start_date) // to_s(step)] += 1

print dict((ts*step + start_date, count) for ts, count in counter.iteritems())
```

The output is the same as the other two solutions.

Comment: Thanks for great answers. I had success with implementing defaultdict solution. It works better then my original approach. I do have access to numpy library.  I tried implementing the numpy approach but keep on gettting this error, also see above code for this as well.    TypeError: ufunc 'less' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule 'safe'

Comment: @user3590149: [click the link in the answer](http://ideone.com/BEyHWK): it contains a *complete* code example that shows how to use `numpy.histogram` in your case. You should avoid kitchen-sink approach in your code: 1. write a simple function that does a *one* job well 2. test it 3. use it to solve a more complex task 4. repeat until the program does what you need. -- at each step you need to worry only about one thing. One of the effects is that you should *not* mix computations (getting the result) and I/O (`print result`) -- it makes writing tests simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it with a single pass on `table`, building a `dict`.  If the table's supposed to be sorted on the `first_alerted_time` field, you can locate the lower and upper bounds for the pass using module `bisect`, then you don't even need the checks on `start_date` and `end_date`, just something like:

```
counts = collections.Counter()
counts.update(datrow['first_alerted_time'].date() 
              for row in table[start_index:end_index])
```

or obvious variants (e.g with `itertools`) if the slice of `table` eats up too much memory.

If `table` can't be assumed to be sorted, the approach is not very different, you just need to add an `if` clause and loop over the whole table:

```
counts = collections.Counter()
counts.update(row['first_alerted_time'].date() 
              for row in table[start_index:end_index]
              if start_date < row['first_alerted_time'] < end_date)
```

If you can clarify what can be assumed about `table` then (if applicable, and you have problems doing it) I can show how to use `bisect` to find the boundaries on a sorted table.

So this gives you a `Counter` with counts by date.  If you need a list sorted by date (e.g of (date, count) pairs), `sorted(counts.items())` will give you that, &c.  Again, if you can clarify exactly what kinds of results are acceptable, and have problems obtaining them, I can show how to do that.

If minutes are also important (as said in the Q's text but not shown in the example code that's said to be working), just replace `row['first_alerted_time'].date()` in either of the above snippets with `row['first_alerted_time'].replace(second=0,microsecond=0)`.  Again, the resulting counter can be sorted, &c.

Comment: I updated my answer. Is that clear on the results. So I want to count the frequency of messages between each interval of a start and end date.

Comment: It seems that your example code only uses dates, not dates + minutes, as the index, which is why I used `date` above.  Easy to fix, let me edit the answer.

Comment: I just missed the API for counter in collections. I"m using 2.6.5. Any suggestions for alternative?

Comment: Use `counts = collections.defaultdict(int)` and a `for` loop such as `for x in`(same things as in the calls to `update` above)`: counts[x] += 1`

Answer (score 0):

You have so many `print` in the loop. I'm not sure they are just debug information or you really wanna print them? I just assume they are debug information.

First, you don't need two loop but one. The first one is totally useless.  Because your interval is `1 minute`, what you can do is change

```
date_to_alert[list_range_of_dates[index]]...
```

TO

```
t = datetime(row['first_alerted_time'].year, row['first_alerted_time'].month, .... row.['first_alerted_time'].minute]
if t in data_to_alert:
    ......
```

So you can get rid of the first loop.

==EDIT==

If the interval is dynamic, you can still calculate the time.

```
def calc(alert_time, interval):
    t =  datetime(row['first_alerted_time'].year, row['first_alerted_time'].month, .... row.['first_alerted_time'].minute]
    from_t = datetime(fromDate.year, fromDate.month, fromDate.day, fromTime.hour, fromTime.minute)
    return (t - from_t) / interval * interval + from_t
```

For example, let say the `from_time` is 10 and `interval` is 5, your bucket will be
`10, 15, 20, 25, ....`

Then

- 17 shall return (17-10) / 5 * 5 + 10 = 15
- 25 shall return (25-10) / 5 * 5 + 10 = 25

And to call this function:

```
t = calc_t(row['first_alerted_time'], interval)
if t in data_to_alert:
    ....
```

==EDIT END==

What's more, if your table, is sorted, you can binary search the start/end row of the table and only count the rows between them which makes your code even faster

==EDIT==

For example

```
1: 2015-01-01-10:00:00
2: 2015-01-01-11:00:00
3: 2015-01-01-12:00:00
4: 2015-01-02-11:13:00
5: 2015-01-02-12:45:00
```

Your from time is 2015-01-01-10:30:00 and end time is 2015-01-02:11:30:00.
So binary search these two timestamps in the table, you only need to work on row 2,3 and 4 but ignore first and last row. This shall increase the speed of your program if you only care about few rows in a super large table. However, this only works if your table is sorted so you can do binary search.

==EDIT END==

Comment: The interval is dyanmic..i use example of 1 min but it can be 2 mins or 2 days or 3 hours.  I"m not sure what you mean by counting the rows between, you mean count the rows between two indexes?

Comment: It's still possible to calculate the index even the interval is dynamic but little bit complicated. I'll update the answer for your question.